# How to send large files though cordova or ionic file transfer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

With Cordova File Transfer, if file size is greater than 2mb then I'm getting an error from the server. How to send large files though cordova or ionic file transfer?

This is the options I am using for cordova file transfer

```
$scope.options = new FileUploadOptions();
$scope.options.fileKey = "file";
$scope.options.fileName = makeFileName();
$scope.options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
$scope.options.chunkedMode=true;
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the question?

Comment: response coming is 502 when i am uploading file less than 2MB then upload is successful but if size is greater than 2MB then i get a response of 502

Comment: Did you write the server that accepts the files?

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts that might help...rather than a definitive answer.

1. 2MB is the default maximum post size for some web/app servers, e.g. Glassfish 3 (fuzzy recollection, but quick look at oracle docs confirmed). Could you just be hitting the default maximum post size? My experience is servers often deploy with a pretty small default maximum size and need to be configured.
2. The 502 Bad Gateway status is not what I would expect for hitting the maximum post size. But maybe you are working through a proxy or gateway of some sort that has a limit, or that obscures the error response. Often with this sort of error the response will include further information, or the server will write further information in its log.

Hard to say without more context about the server and environment, and without a complete error response.